# Partial View Macro File name not updating

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, code-snippets

I am having a problem with the rendering of a Partial View Macro File.
I am new to Umbraco and still learning but I created a Partial View Macro file called "MembersLogin" which is created with a Login Snippet.

But for some reason whenever I try to load it I get this error: "Error loading Partial View script (file: ~/Views/MacroPartials/Members Login.cshtml)"

If you notice the name has a space (" ") and it shouldn't. Because on my Template (View?) where I am Loading it I have written it without space as you can see here:

```
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="main" class="wrapper clearfix">
    <section>
        <h2>@Umbraco.Field("pageName")</h2>
        <p>@Umbraco.Field("bodyText")</p>
        @Umbraco.RenderMacro("MembersLogin")
    </section>
</div>
```

I already tried republishing the entire website but still nothing.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, the problem was that in the Macros Folder the path was wrong because on the first time that I created a Partial View Macro File I did it with a space and it didn't update.